# Why do I get an error "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address." from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

This is very mysterious to me because I have in no way denoted that this parameter refers to an email address (something of the form XXX@XXX.XXX). No attributes, metadata, etc. I have used the word `email` in my naming of variables, but other than that I don't understand how SQL Server is giving me back this error.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="email-address">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eaddr" id="email-address" value="lkassjdkljasdklj@gmail.com">
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
        $.ajax({
            ...,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ...
                Email: $('input[name="eaddr"').val(),
                ...
            }),
            ....
        });
```

**C#:**

```
public Guid? AddPartner ( PartnerInit P )
{
    // returns the id of the partner that was added
    // on error, returns null
    Guid? pid = null;
    // Insert partner to database
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddPartner", this._Conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", P.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", P.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@org_name", P.OrgName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", P.Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region_id", P.RegionId);
        SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@new_guid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) {  Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(output);
        this._Conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        pid = (Guid?)output.Value;
        this._Conn.Close();
    }
```

**T-SQL:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddPartner (@first_name NVARCHAR(50),
                             @last_name NVARCHAR(50),
                             @org_name NVARCHAR(50),
                             @email NVARCHAR(254),
                             @region_id INT,
                             @new_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @T TABLE ( OutputGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER )

      INSERT INTO Partners (first_name, last_name, org_name, email, region_id)
      OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @T
      VALUES (@first_name, @last_name, @org_name, @email, @region_id)

      SELECT @new_guid = OutputGUID FROM @T
  END 
GO
```

This isn't a bug ... I'm just curious how when I type in something like `"blahblahblah"` for the email field it gives me back the error

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail
>   address.

Comment: Perhaps you have an insert trigger on the table that performs validation on the email column.

Comment: Please check your table's definition, especially triggers and check-constraints (column level / table level)

Comment: Can you also supply the full stack trace - this *exact* error message can be raised by the .NET mail components, which is an interesting coincidence. What I'm really asking is, can you confirm how you established the error came from SQL Server - you are, after all, a self-professed "subpar" web dev ;-) (nice name by the way!)

Comment: Are you doing anything else with this email such as sending an email to it when the record is inserted? This is exactly the kind of error normally received when attempting to set a MailAddress of a mail message to a string that it can't recognize as an email.

Comment: Have you confirmed this is not some validation on the web side? For example do you get this message when you run the stored procedure directly in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error message happens whenever you define a `MailAddress` or `MailMessage` object with an invalid mail address.

It seems you don't have a trigger or any kind of constraint on your table columns.